# Prove $\|T(x)\| = \|x\|$ for all $x \in V$ if and only if $\langle T(x),T(y)\rangle = \langle x,y\rangle$ for all $x,y \in V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products

Let $T$ be a linear operator on inner product space $V$. Prove $\|T(x)\| = \|x\|$ for all $x \in V$ if and only if $\langle T(x),T(y)\rangle = \langle x,y\rangle$ for all $x,y \in V$.

For the reverse direction, it is easy, we just set x=y, what to do with the forward direction?

What facts to use to prove this and general idea in approaching this problem?

Comment: Do you know of the Polarisation Identity?

Comment: @user744868 Yes, but is there another way to prove it?

Comment: Nothing so elementary. Why do you ask?

Comment: @user744868 I have done those identities before, and is that problem limited to those identities?

Comment: More or less, yes. There's no simpler way of expressing the inner product in terms of norms that I'm aware of. All the other ways I can think of proving this use heavier machinery, and are akin to using a nuclear warhead to kill a fly.

Comment: @user744868 I see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can approach it alternatively as
\begin{align*}
\langle T(x+y),T(x+y)\rangle & = \langle T(x) + T(y),T(x) + T(y)\rangle\\\\
& = \langle T(x),T(x)\rangle + 2\langle T(x),T(y)\rangle + \langle T(y),T(y)\rangle\\\\
& = \|T(x)\|^{2} + 2\langle T(x),T(y)\rangle + \|T(y)\|^{2}
\end{align*}

On the other hand, one has that
\begin{align*}
\langle x+y,x+y\rangle & = \langle x,x\rangle + 2\langle x,y\rangle + \langle y,y\rangle\\\\
& = \|x\|^{2} + 2\langle x,y\rangle + \|y\|^{2}
\end{align*}

Since both expressions are equal and $T$ is an isometry, we can conclude that
\begin{align*}
\|T(x)\|^{2} + 2\langle T(x),T(y)\rangle + \|T(y)\|^{2} = \|x\|^{2} + 2\langle x,y\rangle + \|y\|^{2} \Longrightarrow \langle T(x),T(y)\rangle = \langle x,y\rangle
\end{align*}
and we are done with case where the field $\textbf{F} = \textbf{R}$.

Let us suppose now that $\textbf{F} = \textbf{C}$. To begin with, we should notice that
\begin{align*}
\langle T(x+y),T(x+y)\rangle & = \langle T(x) + T(y),T(x) + T(y)\rangle\\\\
& = \langle T(x),T(x)\rangle + \langle T(x),T(y)\rangle + \langle T(y),T(x)\rangle + \langle T(y),T(y)\rangle\\\\
& = \|T(x)\|^{2}  + \langle T(x),T(y)\rangle + \overline{\langle T(x),T(y)\rangle} + \|T(y)\|^{2}\\\\
& = \|T(x)\|^{2} + 2\text{Re}\langle T(x),T(y)\rangle + \|T(y)\|^{2}
\end{align*}
Similarly, one does also have that
\begin{align*}
\langle x+y,x+y\rangle & = \langle x,x\rangle + \langle x,y\rangle + \langle y,x\rangle + \langle y,y\rangle\\\\
& = \|x\|^{2} + \langle x,y\rangle + \overline{\langle x,y\rangle} + \|y\|^{2}\\\\
& = \|x\|^{2} + 2\text{Re}\langle x,y\rangle + \|y\|^{2}
\end{align*}
Therefore, since both expressions are equal and $T$ is an isometry, $\text{Re}\langle T(x),T(y)\rangle = \text{Re}\langle x,y\rangle$.

On the other hand, one has that
\begin{align*}
\langle T(x+iy),T(x+iy)\rangle & = \langle T(x) + iT(y), T(x) + iT(y)\rangle\\\\
& = \langle T(x),T(x)\rangle + \langle T(x),iT(y)\rangle + \langle iT(y),T(x)\rangle + \langle iT(y),iT(y)\rangle\\\\
& = \|T(x)\|^{2} - i\langle T(x),T(y)\rangle + i\langle T(y),T(x)\rangle + \|T(y)\|^{2}\\\\
& = \|T(x)\|^{2} - i\langle T(x),T(y)\rangle + i \overline{\langle T(x),T(y)\rangle} + \|T(y)\|^{2}\\\\
& = \|T(x)\|^{2} + 2\text{Im}\langle T(x),T(y)\rangle + \|T(y)\|^{2}
\end{align*}
which is equal to
\begin{align*}
\langle x + iy,x+iy\rangle & = \langle x,x\rangle + \langle x,iy\rangle + \langle iy,x\rangle + \langle iy,iy\rangle\\\\
& = \|x\|^{2} - i\langle x,y\rangle + i\overline{\langle x,y\rangle} + \|y\|^{2}\\\\
& = \|x\|^{2} + 2\text{Im}\langle x,y\rangle + \|y\|^{2}
\end{align*}
Since $T$ is an isometry, we conclude that $\text{Im}\langle T(x),T(y)\rangle = \text{Im}\langle x,y\rangle$.

Finally, gathering both results, we conclude that $\langle T(x),T(y)\rangle = \langle x,y\rangle$, just as desired.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 5):

In essence, your proof utilized the fact that you can write the norm in terms of the inner product. To do the reverse direction, you'd want to write the inner product in terms of the norm. I hope this is enough to start you off. I'll include a solution as a spoiler below.

> We compute that $|x + y|^2 = \langle x + y, x + y \rangle = \langle x, x + y \rangle + \langle y, x + y \rangle = \langle x, x \rangle + \langle x, y \rangle + \langle y, x \rangle + \langle y, y \rangle$. Rewriting this, we get $|x + y|^2 = |x|^2 + 2 \langle x, y \rangle + |y|^2$. Hence, $\langle x, y \rangle = \frac{1}{2} (|x + y|^2 - |x|^2 - |y|^2)$. Hence, if $|T(x)| = |x|$ for all $x$ then $\langle T(x), T(y) \rangle = \frac{1}{2} (|T(x) + T(y)|^2 - |T(x)|^2 - |T(y)|^2) = \frac{1}{2} (|x + y|^2 - |x|^2 - |y|^2) = \langle x, y \rangle.$

Comment: It's worth noting that this proof assumes the inner product space is real. A little more work needs to be done to establish the complex case.

Comment: Right, good catch. For the complex case, this will only give you a formula for the real part of the inner product. Slight modifications should also yield a formula for the imaginary part.